# User ES6 `import` to load a JSON file?

Tags: javascript, json, module, ecmascript-6

In node.js, it is possible to load a JSON file by using require:

```js
$ node
> let data = require('./data.json')
undefined
> data
[ { a: 1 }, { a: 10 }, { a: 100 } ]
```

Is it possible to do this with the new ES6 `import` method?

It would be useful to do something like:

*In data.json…*

```json
[ { a: 1 }, { a: 10 }, { a: 100 } ]
```

*In loader.html…*

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>ES6 modules tryout</title>
    <script src="load.js" type="module"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

*In load.js…*

```js
import * as data from './data.json'
```

…but that results in the error:

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost/data.json”.
```

Because in a JSON module you can’t use `export` and `default`, is there some way to import everything from a JSON file and give it a name with `import`, or I need to stick with the older method of using an asyncrhonous call like this?

```js
fetch('data.json')
  .then(r => r.json())
  .then(data => /* something with data */)
```

Comment: have you tested it ? what happened ?

Comment: Yes, I got `Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost/data.json”.`

I will update my post with more detail about my attempt.

Comment: The `import` *syntax* doesn't care what you load (well, it needs to be JavaScript). It's the *module loader's* responsibility to resolve the module specifier and produce JavaScript code. The module loader is not part of the JavaScript specification. So it really depends on in which environment the code is executed or which module bundler you are using. If you are running the code in node then it will be possible. If you are using a module bundler such as webpack then you have to configure it properly. If neither then the answer is probably that it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, but the feature is still experimental. Run your Node.js program with the followig command flags `node --experimental-modules --experimental-json-modules your-filename.mjs`